# Managing the test cases , scenarios and feature files with specflow

Tags: bdd, specflow

I have number of different manual test cases which needs to be automated with the Specflow .

There are multiple test cases multiple scenarios.  SO there will be multiple feature files ?

We are following Sprint system. each sprint has 100+ test cases which are going to be automated.

Which will be the best practice for managing the test cases and scenarios using the feature files ?  Theres no point in creating same set of functions everytime for different test cases.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'manual test cases'? How are these defined? Are they just written down in a document? Are they some specific format for some specific tool? Please give some more details, and if possible some examples.

Comment: We have set of manual test cases which are to be picked up from the tfs.  there are number of them.  We are team of 3 automation testers working on the same test cases.  how are we going to manage the set of test cases and how are we going to create multiple feature files.

Comment: you still didn't define 'manual test cases' :). Is this a text file or word document with a description of the test? Is this some TFS specific concept? As I said before an example would be very useful in helping you to solve your problem

Comment: are you talking about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293545.aspx)?

Comment: I have editedf the question , sorry for the confusion.ok so let me just say , i have test cases which are many.  thats a different topic.  I want to automate the test cases using specflow. There will definitly be many many scenarios and feature files. so how will i manage these scenarios and feature files given we also have 2 more automation testers working.  so in short i would want to know how will i manage test cases , scenarios and feature files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would manage this the same as you would manage any other code files. Make changes, if the changes conflict with others changes then merge the changes before you check in.

The best way to avoid merge issues is to try and work in different areas. Create many feature files as then multiple people can work on different features at one time and you won't have conflicts.

Communication between the testers is important in avoiding conflicts as well, and in the case of scenarios in specflow it will be important in ensuring that you use consistent step names. Also checking in often will ensure that you minimise the number of merge issues, even after each scenario has been created.

**EDIT**

based on your edited question in specflow all steps are global, so if feature1 has a scenario with a step `Given a user 'Bob' is logged in` and Feature32 also has a scenarion with the step  `Given a user 'Tom' is logged in` then they will both share the same step source code and so the same function will be reused.

As long as you write your steps in a consistent manner (ie use the same text) then you should get excellent reuse of functions across all of your hundreds of features and scenarios.

Comment: @ArpanBuch updated my answer. To be honest it would be better if you used specflow for a while and then asked specific questions about it, as it seems from your question that you have not actually tried to use it yet